# Elasticsearch: How to add nested datatype using Java api?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-java-api

Example::

```
"price":{  
       "type":"nested",  --> how to add this using java api 
       "properties":{  
          "activity_price":{  
             "type":"double"
          },
          "multimedia_price":{  
             "type":"double"
          },
          "transportation_price":{  
             "type":"double"
          }
       }
    }
```

Actually I want to add "type" :"nested" in mapping.json
To find nested object, I am using nested query. But getting
**"[nested] failed to find nested object under path [...]"**.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    "nested" : {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "match" : {
                "price.activity_price" : {
                  "query" : 1.0,
                }
              }
            }]
        }
      },
      "path" : "price",
      "ignore_unmapped" : false,
      "score_mode" : "none",
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
```

This is how nested query supposed to be. Finally error has been gone and returned expected result.